# Type I group von Neumann algebra

Tags: lie-groups, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. One says that $G$ is type I if its *full* group $C^*$ algebra is type I. Since being type I passes to quotients and generated von Neumann algebras, if $G$ is type I then *reduced* group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_r(G)$ and group von Neumann algebra $L(G)$ are also type I.

I have two "converse" questions: let $G$ be a general locally compact group.

1. Assume that $C^*_r(G)$ is type I. Does it follow that $C^*(G)$ is type I?
2. Assume that $L(G)$ is type I. Does it follow that $C^*_r(G)$ is type I?

I vaguely remember that the answer to 2. is negative, but I cannot find a source.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the visitors to this page, perhaps it is useful to list some preliminaries & definitions first.

A $C^*$-algebra $A$ is Type I iff it is GCR/postliminal iff $A^{**}$ is a Type I von Neumann algebra.

A von Neumann algebra is said to be *atomic* if it is generated by its minimal projections, equivalently if it is isomorphic to $(\bigoplus_{i\in J} B(H_i))_{\ell^{\infty}}$ for some set of Hilbert spaces $\{H_i:i\in J\}$. Clearly an atomic von Neumann algebra is Type I.

A locally compact group $G$ is said to be of class $[AR]$ if its regular representation is completely reducible a.k.a. its regular representation is *atomic*. $G$ is of $[AR]$ iff $VN(G)$ (another notation for $L(G)$) is an atomic von Neumann algebra, see Theorems 3.5 & 4.1 in [[Taylor1983](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01455310)].

$C_r^*(G)=C^*(G)$ iff $G$ is amenable. If $G$ is not amenable, there exists a surjective homomorphism $\phi:C^*(G)\to C_r^*(G)$ that fixes each $f\in L^1(G)$.

---

For the 2nd question, there exist totally disconnected LCGs of $[AR]$ that aren't Type I, please see Theorem 4.1 and the remark after in [[Blackadar1977](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(77)90073-8)]. Also, Baggett and Taylor had provided connected LCGs of $[AR]$ in [[BaggettTaylor1978](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1978-0509261-X)], one of which is amenable & not Type I. For these groups, $VN(G)$ is atomic so Type I, whereas $(C_r^*(G))^{**} = (C^*(G))^{**} = W^*(G)$ (the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra) is not Type I.

I don't have an answer for the 1st question, although if there exists a counterexample $G$, it must be non-amenable and non-Type I.